# Review queues / Suggested Edits: Differences in set of possible actions

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When reviewing some post as part of the *Suggested Edits* queue, I, most generally, get 4 choices (Approve / Improve edit / Reject and edit / Reject).
I, sometimes, albeit not often, get only 2 choices offered: Approve / Reject.

Am I alone with this (browser version dependent? / user history dependent?) 
Are there conditions commanding the actions left to the reviewer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have ≥ 5000 rep (as *you* do),
you get to see pending ***tag** (wiki)* edits
in the “Suggested edits” queue (and vote to approve or reject them). 
However, if you have < 20000 rep (as *you* do),
you do *not* get the “Improve edit” and “Reject and edit” options
for tag (wiki) edits,
because you don't have the privilege
to edit tag wikis without needing approval.

Reference:

- [privilege to approve tag wiki edits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) (5,000)
- [“trusted users” are allowed to perform trusted actions,
  including … editing tag wikis without needing approval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (20,000)

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.